# Access Docker container /home folder on host

Tags: docker, ubuntu-server

I have been having the hardest time with this, I run a Minecraft server through Docker and I've been needing to edit configs, upload folders/configs and whatnot to the server. The obvious way would be to FTP into the host an access the 'synced' folder though the host's filesystem. I've tried:

```
 docker run -v `pwd`/src/mc:/home/minecraft/mcmyadmin/Minecraft jchaney/mcmyadmin
```

but the /src/mc folder is empty and the container never works:

```
    McMyAdmin Updater - 2.2.0.0

Running in 64-bit mode.
Notice  : Detecting System...
Notice  : No virtualized environment detected.
Notice  : Linux Distribution: Unknown Distribution
Notice  : Detection complete.
Warning : No Minecraft configuration file found (Normal on a first start)
Notice  : Detected Java runtime version 1.7.0
Notice  : Checking for Minecraft Server updates...
Notice  : Updating Minecraft server...
Notice  : Downloading latest Minecraft server...
Notice  : Error downloading file.
Downloading Game Server: -1%Notice  : Download failed!
Notice  : Starting McMyAdmin Personal v2.5.2.4
Warning : No saved group information was found. Loading Defaults.
Notice  : Upgraded 4 legacy groups
Notice  : No saved schedule was found. Loading Defaults.
Notice  : Checking for updates...
Notice  : Checking for Minecraft Server updates...
Notice  : Starting webserver...
Notice  : McMyAdmin has started and is ready for use.
Notice  : This is the first time McMyAdmin has been started.
Notice  : You must complete the first-start wizard via the web interface.
```

It becomes unresponsive (and notice the download error).

Any ideas?

In case it wasn't clear, these configs would need to be edited, so a copy in the beginning would only work once, rebuilding this to edit configs is inconvenient.

Comment: What if it's a prebuilt container? As in docker pull (CID)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dockerfile with COPY commands to build the container with all the configs/files that you need.

Comment: What if it's a prebuilt container (I.E. docker pull <container>)